Unable to change server url in nginx reverse proxy. It tries to use the url at / rather than going to the new one
I have two routes one is "/" and the other is "/model-management-page". / is a gunicorn .sock host and the other is a host running on a static ip.
However when I run the nginx reverse proxy, the "/" host works fine but "model-management page wont load". If I flip the two and put the .sock file in the /model page and the IP:4000 in the "/" then only the IP:4000 host will load.
I am not sure why this is happening, am I missing a piece of the configuration which should allow the proxy to change IPs. However, this issue does not exist for my "/dicom-web" route, which makes this more frustrating.
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;


        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

}



server {


        root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        location /dicom-web/ {
            proxy_pass https://IP:8042; # Update this if your API is hosted elsewhere

            rewrite /orthanc(.*) $1 break;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        }

        location /model-management-page-login {
        add_header Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy cross-origin;
            proxy_pass http://IP:4000; # Update this if your API is hosted elsewhere

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        }

    location /api/add-user {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /api/get-current-user-id {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location / {

    
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/path/socketfile.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    # WebSocket support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Origin "";
    }


    location /docs {
    
    index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /ad {
        index advertisement.html advertisement.htm;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

I have tried adding proxy_pass and associated commands such as $HOST... to route the IP to be the host when clicked. I have tried to use the dicom-web route since that does not have this issue. I have tried adding cors headers but turns out that was another issue which I already solved.
